# Can i call .ctp file from another model in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I want to call a .ctp file in one 'Model' and the .ctp file is in another 'View'.
Is it possible in cakephp?

Or instead of that should i call that 'Controller' function in my 'Model'?

Comment: Can u post a small example of what u really need..?

Comment: Before trying a MVC framework you might want to read about OOP and design patters like MVC -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: checkout this site: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html and take a deeper look at "elements". i think its possible thats this is what you are looking for: **elements: smaller, reusable bits of view code. Elements are usually rendered inside of views.**

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP in a nutshell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html), and the keywords that you might need to search for:

- `Dispatcher` and `Routing` controlling how URL reaches your controller.
- `Controller` places system logic and controlling individual routing requests from `Dispatcher`

  - `Component` places logics that can be easily shared by `Controller`s
- `Model` is for all the database related queries, manipulation, selections, deletions

  - `Behavior` can be deem as similar to `Component`, that provides "mixins" to Models to achieve similar behaviors, such as `TreeBehavior` abstract your database tables into parent-child relationship.
- `View` is used by `Controller` to render individual pages to the user

  - `Helper` placed shared functionalities to help View render certain stuff. For example, `FormHelper` helps you all sort of form rendering, inputs, etc.
- Place globally shared library in `app/Lib` folder so it can be easily accessed through using `App::uses('...', 'Lib')`. For example, a `Gravatar` library that helps you convert emails to md5-hashed strings. So this can be used everywhere in your app.
- `vendors` are for those packaged vendor libraries that do not respect MVC, for example, `swiftmailer` that helps you send emails. Usually I would abstract them into my `Lib` folder for ease.
- [`plugins`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) are for those baked CakePHP applications found everywhere in the internet.

There are others in-depth stuff that you might be interested in, but these are the most basic stuff that you need to know before using a MVC framework like CakePHP. [Check out their docs before diving in](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access View (.ctp) in Model, it's against MVC architecture and logic. Just tell us more what do you want to do, maybe you're doing something wrong.